# Difference between SQLite Temporary DB and InMemory DB

Tags: database, sqlite

What is the difference between SQLite InMemory DB and Temporary DB ?

Reference: [Temporary DB](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#temp_db)

While I expect Temporary DB is a disk backed file DB, the documentation is little confusing as it says temporary DB is almost same as in memory DB.

I am looking for a temporary disk file DB, where records are written to file on the disk.
If temporary DB are stored as file on the disk, where do I find them ? I understand that when the connection is closed the DB cease to exist but while the connection is open I expect to find the DB on the disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#temp_db) you linked to says:

> Even though a disk file is allocated for each temporary database, in practice the temporary database usually resides in the in-memory pager cache and hence is very little difference between a pure in-memory database created by ":memory:" and a temporary database created by an empty filename. The sole difference is that a ":memory:" database must remain in memory at all times whereas parts of a temporary database might be flushed to disk if database becomes large or if SQLite comes under memory pressure.

The default location for temporary database files is the temporary directory, with a file name like `etilqs_*`.
But as mentioned above, often it is not necessary for the data to be actually stored in this file.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, how do I configure when the records are stored to disk. I am trying to use SQLite because there are millions of records which cannot be kept in memory. So, looking to configure params such that SQLite uses memory as less as possible (in the order of few 10 MBs).

Comment: For temporary databases, this is done [in the same way](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) as for other databases.